# Solidworks Property Manager Page - 2 buttons on same line

Tags: visual-studio, api, add-in, solidworks

I'm building my own Solidworks Addin and while building it, I encountered a difficulty.

Anybody knows how to Create 2 buttons side-by-side in a Property Manager Page? I tried the different possibilities of the  *swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e* enum without any success.

The idea is I want people to select from the configurations list, every configuration they want the server to proccess. Therefore I created 4 buttons (SelectAll/SelectHighlighted/DeSelectHighlighted/DeSelectAll) to help the users in their selections.

Here's what it looks like at the moment :

[image: PMP]

```
                //Ajout Controls Group_Configs
            lst_Configs_All = Group_Configs.AddControl2(lst_Configs_All_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_Listbox, "Configurations", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_LeftEdge, (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Enabled + (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Visible, "Liste des configurations du modèle actif");
            lst_Configs_All.Height = 180;
            lst_Configs_All.Style = (int)swPropMgrPageListBoxStyle_e.swPropMgrPageListBoxStyle_NoIntegralHeight;

            BitmapHandler iBmp = new BitmapHandler();
            string BitmapFileName = iBmp.CreateFileFromResourceBitmap("Willy.Controller.Template.btnConfigs.bmp", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()));


            // string BitmapFileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)); //& "\" & _SwAddin.BitMapsFolder & "Select2.bmp"

            btn_Configs_SelectAll = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_SelectAll_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Tout Sélectionner", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_LeftEdge, (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Enabled + (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Visible, "Sélectionner toutes les configurations");
            btn_Configs_SelectAll.SetBitmapsByName3(BitmapFileName, "");

            btn_Configs_Select = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_Select_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Sélectionner les configuration surlignées", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_Indent, (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Enabled + (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Visible, "Sélectionner les configuration surlignées");
            btn_Configs_Select.SetBitmapsByName3(BitmapFileName, "");

            btn_Configs_DeSelect = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_DeSelect_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Désélectionner les configuration surlignées", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_Indent, (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Enabled + (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Visible, "Désélectionner les configuration surlignées");
            btn_Configs_DeSelect.SetBitmapsByName3(BitmapFileName, "");

            btn_Configs_DeSelectAll = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_DeSelectAll_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Désélectionner toutes les configuration", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_Indent, (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Enabled + (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Visible, "Désélectionner toutes les configuration");
            btn_Configs_DeSelectAll.SetBitmapsByName3(BitmapFileName, "");

            lst_Configs_ToDo = Group_Configs.AddControl2(lst_Configs_ToDo_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_Listbox, "Configurations", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_LeftEdge, (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Enabled + (int)swAddControlOptions_e.swControlOptions_Visible, "Liste des configurations à générer");
            lst_Configs_ToDo.Height = 180;
            lst_Configs_ToDo.Style = (int)swPropMgrPageListBoxStyle_e.swPropMgrPageListBoxStyle_NoIntegralHeight;
```

Comment: I have tried, unsuccessfully to do the same in the past. Reference [these](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/19252) [two](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/21664) SolidWorks forum posts for potential solutions. Neither have worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so i think after some research I found a way to get through this.

[Source](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/29284)

You need to cast your BitmapButton to it's parent object (PropertyManagerPageControl) to access the Top and Left Property. You may then set the pixels to whatever you need to.

EDIT : Here's what I have manager to do. I'm also including the code.

[image: Visual]

```
            btn_Configs_SelectAll = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_SelectAll_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Tout Sélectionner", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_Indent, options, "Sélectionner toutes les configurations");
        string[] imageList = new string[1];
        imageList[0] = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\View\Bitmaps\btnConfigs_SelectAll.bmp";
        btn_Configs_SelectAll.SetBitmapsByName3(imageList, imageList);
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_SelectAll).Top = 140;
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_SelectAll).Left = 0;

        btn_Configs_Select = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_Select_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Sélectionner les configuration surlignées", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_Indent, options, "Sélectionner les configuration surlignées");
        string[] imageList2 = new string[1];
        imageList2[0] = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\View\Bitmaps\btnConfigs_Select.bmp";
        btn_Configs_Select.SetBitmapsByName3(imageList2, imageList2);
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_Select).Top = 140;
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_Select).Left = 30;

        btn_Configs_DeSelect = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_DeSelect_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Désélectionner les configuration surlignées", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_Indent, options, "Désélectionner les configuration surlignées");
        string[] imageList3 = new string[1];
        imageList3[0] = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\View\Bitmaps\btnConfigs_DeSelect.bmp";
        btn_Configs_DeSelect.SetBitmapsByName3(imageList3, imageList3);
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_DeSelect).Top = 140;
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_DeSelect).Left = 60;

        btn_Configs_DeSelectAll = Group_Configs.AddControl2(btn_Configs_DeSelectAll_ID, (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlType_e.swControlType_BitmapButton, "Désélectionner toutes les configuration", (int)swPropertyManagerPageControlLeftAlign_e.swControlAlign_Indent, options, "Désélectionner toutes les configuration");
        string[] imageList4 = new string[1];
        imageList4[0] = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\View\Bitmaps\btnConfigs_DeSelectAll.bmp";
        btn_Configs_DeSelectAll.SetBitmapsByName3(imageList4, imageList4);
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_DeSelectAll).Top = 140;
        ((PropertyManagerPageControl)btn_Configs_DeSelectAll).Left = 90;
```